# How to sort a PriorityQueue when custom object attribute changes?

Tags: java, collections, heap, comparator, priority-queue

I am trying to implement a PriorityQueue in java with custom Comparator for this class where sorting is based on member1.

```
    class Custom
{
    int member1;
    int member2;
    public Custom(int n, int m)
    {
        this.member1 = n;
        this.member2 = m;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.member1+" "+this.member2;
    }
}
```

Initially I have created two objects and added them to the PQ and it is sorted as expected. But when I go and change the value of member1 for one of the objects, the queue is in the wrong order when I poll(). How do I achieve this functionality ? In short, once a object is added to the PQ, it does not consider if the object's attribute has changed later.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove this object from queue and add back so it is ordered correctly. Queue is not aware about mutations of objects that are inside.

Comment: can you share a reference to this so that I can read about this indepth. You are correct but I want to have a deep dive. I was trying to figure this out to implement dijkstra algorithm.

Comment: There's not a _good_ solution to this in Java.  Typical Java implementations of Dijkstra's algorithm will simply add a _new_ `Custom` value to the queue, and skip entries from the queue for already-visited vertices.